# Codeigniter controller detecting ajax file upload

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

I have set up my Codeigniter application so that I can upload files via Ajax. I followed this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/

My original form checked to see if an ajax request had been called, if not then I had the fallback CI form validation / error messages showing instead.

I checked this using - `$this->input->is_ajax_request()`

My code looked like this:

```
if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
   // process ajax form data
} else {
   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) { 
      $data['success'] = 0;
      $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
   } else {
      $data['success'] = 1;
   }
   $this->load->view('form', $data);
}
```

After doing some investigation I discovered that I couldn't apply the same technique because it isn't actually an ajax request, therefore I am not sure how I can use this approach. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great. I don't like it being totally dependent on ajax, I like having a fallback option. I noticed in the comments that someone has set up a CSFR cookie in their ajaxfileupload.js but to be honest I'm not too hot with js so I wouldn't know where to begin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX request along with everything else you could post key/value:

```
ajax : 1
```

Then in your controller:

```
if( $this->input->post('ajax') == 1 ) {
  // process ajax form data
}
else
{
  // form validation
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah of course, I think I always try to over complicate things. This should work perfectly, thanks.